# Observer combined with Template Pattern

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I used the template pattern for an algorithm I'm writing. But I combined it with the observer pattern to get informed about the process.

```
public abstract class Test extends Observable
```

In the method for the algorithm i call the notify

```
public final void findSolution() {
 // run algorithm
 notifyObservers();
}
```

This abstract class with the findSolution method will be extended by different algorithm implementations. The UI just keeps a reference to the Test and calls the findSolution() but the update method from the ui will never be invoked does anybody now what is wrong?

```
public class CreateViewResults implements Observer {
 private Test algorithm;

 public CreateViewResults() {
  algorithm = new OneTestImpl();
  algorithm.addObserver(this);
  algorithm.findSolution();
 }

 @Override
 public update( Observable ob, Object o ) {
  System.out.println("Update");
 }

}
```

Comment: You'd have to show us the code for OneTestImpl. My first guess would be that OneTestImpl.findSolution neither calls super nor notifyObservers.

Comment: @Jay: OneTestImpl.findSolution is inherited from Test, and can't be overridden since it's final.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Good point. I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing happens because the observable hasn't changed.

From [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers%28%29):

> If this object has changed, as indicated by the hasChanged method,
>   then notify all of its observers and then call the clearChanged method
>   to indicate that this object has no longer changed.

You should thus call `setChanged()` before notifying the observers.